# scroll horizontally for carousel

Tags: jquery

I have made a **carousel**. used `scrollLeft()` in it. you can see it on [CODEOPEN LINK](https://codepen.io/fr_sdgh/pen/woLeeB)

```
  // For show/hide arrows button.
        carousel.scroll(function() {
            var i = carousel.scrollLeft();
            var w = carousel.width();
            console.log(i+'='+w);

            if (i == w) {
                next.fadeOut(400);
            } else {
                next.fadeIn(400);
            };
            if (i == 0) {
                prev.fadeOut(400);
            } else {
                prev.fadeIn(400);
            };
        });
```

My problem is  when the page is at full width (1200px) it works properly but when I resize the browser, `scrollLeft()` return different value. You can see values in **console.log**.

I expect when `scrollLeft()` reaches the end **next button** gets hidden. But when the width is less than **1200px** it doesn't have the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problem with your code. It's showing that functions like swipeleft and swiperight are not defined as you can see it in your codepen console.
And the another thing is that on first time you are not hiding previous element. On load your slide always will be at 0 position, so there is no need to keep it always, and rest time it's working fine. 
You can see my fiddle here for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/or8pege7/2/ and correct code as well.

```
var slide = $("#slide");
        var carousel = $("#wrapper-slide");
        var next = $("#next-btn-carousel");
        var prev = $("#prev-btn-carousel");

    // For show/hide arrows button.
        carousel.scroll(function() {
            var i = carousel.scrollLeft();
            var w = carousel.width();
            /*console.log(w);
            console.log(i);*/
            if (i == w) {
                next.fadeOut(400);
            } else {
                next.fadeIn(400);
            };
            if (i == 0) {
                prev.fadeOut(400);
            } else {
                prev.fadeIn(400);
            };
        });

    //For action next.
        function goNext() {
            var i = carousel.scrollLeft();
            var w = carousel.width();
            console.log(i+'='+w);
            carousel.animate({
                scrollLeft: (i += w)
            }, 1000, "swing");
        };
        if(carousel.scrollLeft()==0){
            $('#prev-btn-carousel').hide();
        }

        next.click(function() {
            goNext();
        });

        /*carousel.swipeleft(function(){
            goNext();
        });*/

    //For action prev.
        function goPrev() {
            var i = carousel.scrollLeft();
            var w = carousel.width();
            console.log(i+'='+w);
            carousel.animate({
                scrollLeft: (i -= w)
            }, 800, "swing");
        };

        prev.click(function() {
            goPrev();
        });

        /*carousel.swiperight(function(){
            goPrev();
        });*/


        carousel.on("dragstart", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: It was good point for hide the **prev button** on first time but my problem still there for the **next button**. It doesn't have desired behavior when I decrease it less then **1200px**.

Comment: For use **swipe** on **CODEOPEN** or other editors online, What should I do?

Comment: First let you tell me is swiperight or swipelef a jquery core function?